# Tabs with Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Following is the `App`:

```
import { createElement as ce, Component } from 'react';
import SectionOne from './components/sections/SectionOne';
import SectionTwo from './components/sections/SectionTwo';
import TopMenu from './components/menu';


class App extends Component {

  constructor( props ) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      activeIndex: 1,
    }
    this.displaySection = this.displaySection.bind(this);
  }

  displaySection( activeIndex ) {
    this.setState({ activeIndex });
  }

  render(){
    const { displaySection, activeIndex } = this.state;
    const sections = [ SectionOne, SectionTwo ];

    return (
      ce('div', null,
        ce(TopMenu, { activeIndex, sectionClicked: this.displaySection }, null),
        ce(sections[activeIndex], null),
      )
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

`Sections` are as follows:

```
import { createElement as ce } from 'react';

const SectionOne = () =>
  ce('div', {
      className: 'sections section-one',
      tabIndex: 0,
      id: 'about-me'
    },
    ce('h1', null,
      'I am John Doe.',
      ce('span', null, 'Hello World!'),
    ),
    ce('div', { className: 'about-me' },
      ce('h2', null, 'A little about me: '),
      ce('p', null, 'TEXT'),
      ce('p', null, 'MORE TEXT'),
    )
  );


export default SectionOne;
```

Following is the menu:

```
import { createElement as ce } from 'react';
import { v4 } from 'uuid';


const menuItems = [ 'about me', 'skills', 'work', 'contact me' ];

const TopMenu = ({ activeIndex = 0, sectionClicked = f => f }) =>
  ce('ul', {className: 'top-menu'},
    menuItems.map( (item, i) =>
      ce('li', {
        className: 'top-menu-item',
        onClick: () => sectionClicked( i ),
        tabIndex: i,
        key: v4(),
      },
        item
      ))
    );

export default TopMenu;
```

I am trying to pass the tabIndex / i to the `App` through a callback function but it is not working.

Comment: missing `this`.. `sectionClicked: this.displaySection`

Comment: oh you're trying to get it from `state`.. it's not on state though, it's just on the component.

Comment: Nice, that worked. Silly mistake.

Comment: Is there a flaw in the logic here? The way I am trying to accomplish this I mean.

Comment: no looks fine. if you had a lot of tabs in the your conditional to figure out which tab to display would probably get quite tedious. you could instead put all your sections in an array then just display `sections[activeIndex]`

Comment: Nice,thanks. I edited the `render` method in `App`.